# Problema con permisos AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, permisos

Intento que mi aplicación solicite y verifique los permisos.

int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

El problema es que android studio me da error en la palabra "permission"

¿Alguien sabe alguna solución?

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera.También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: antes de la palabra manifest coloca android, ej: android.manifest.permission......

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto el trozo de código, si puedes añadir más información sobre el contexto en el que lo estás llamando o algo sería de ayuda.

Comment: estoy tratando de que mi app verifique los permisos de ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Y en el Main Activity al ingresar ese trozo de codigo solo me da error en la palabra permission :c

Comment: Copia el código de tu MainActivity para poder verlo.

Comment: package com.example.ikki.gpstest;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

           }
}

Comment: ese es :c ayuda